# Separable non-flat simple ring extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, flatness, separable-algebras

Let $R \subseteq S$ be two commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebras such that:

**(1)** $R$ and $S$ are integral domains.

**(2)** $Q(R)=Q(S)$, namely, their fields of fractions are equal.

**(3)** $S=R[w]$, for some $w \in S$.

**(4)** $S$ is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_algebra) over $R$, namely, $S$ is a projective $S \otimes_R S$-module via $f: S \otimes_R S 
\to S$ given by: $f(s_1 \otimes_R s_2)=s_1s_2$.

> Should such $S$ be flat over $R$? I guess no, so please it would be nice to see a counterexample.

> Is there a fifth condition that would guarantee flatness of $R \subseteq S$?

Perhaps adding a fifth condition **(5)** $R$ is a UFD (or at least integrally closed) would guarantee
flatness of $R \subseteq S$? (I am not sure).

The above is (almost) question 3 of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371948/separability-of-mathbbcx-over-its-mathbbc-subalgebras) question.
Also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830436/example-of-non-flat-r-subseteq-rw) without comments.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R$ to be the coordinate ring of the nodal curve $\mathbb{C}[t^2-1, t(t^2-1)]$ and $S$ to be its normalization $\mathbb{C}[t]$. It satisfies (1), ..., (4): The first three are immediate. For (4), note that since $R$ is noetherian, the projectivity of $S$ as an $S \otimes_R S$-module is equivalent to $S$ being unramified over $R$ (Theorem 2.5 in Auslander-Buchsbaum, *On Ramification Theory in Noetherian Rings*, American Journal of Mathematics, 1959). It is enough to check that maximal ideals are unramified. Since we are in equi-characteristic zero, it suffices to show that for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $S$, $(\mathfrak{q} \cap R) S_{\mathfrak{q}} = \mathfrak{q} S_{\mathfrak{q}}$. Let $\mathfrak{q} = (t-\alpha)$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.
Then $(\mathfrak{q} \cap R) S = 
(t^2 - \alpha^2, t(t^2-1)- \alpha(\alpha^2-1))$.
If $\alpha \neq 0$, then $t+\alpha \not \in \mathfrak{q}$
so $t-\alpha \in (\mathfrak{q} \cap R)S_{\mathfrak{q}}$.
If $\alpha = 0$, then $t^2-1 \not \in \mathfrak{q}$
so $t \in (\mathfrak{q} \cap R)S_{\mathfrak{q}}$.
Either way, $(\mathfrak{q} \cap R)S_{\mathfrak{q}} = 
\mathfrak{q}S_{\mathfrak{q}}$. However, $S$ is not a flat $R$-module.

Further comments:

1. If $R$ is noetherian and $R \rightarrow S$ is a finite (as it is in the
   example), then $S$ is $R$-flat if and only if it is $R$-projective; since
   $\mathrm{Spec} R$ is connected, for every prime $R$-ideal $\mathfrak{p}$,
   the fibre $\dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})}\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) \otimes_R S$
   does not depend on $\mathfrak{p}$, so $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) \otimes_R S =
   \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$, since $Q(R) = Q(S)$. Hence for maximal $R$-ideals
   $\mathfrak{p}$, the map $R/\mathfrak{p} \to S/\mathfrak{p}S$ is an
   isomorphism; by the Nakayama lemma, $S/R = 0$, i.e., $S=R$.
2. If $w = \frac{1}{r}$ for some $r \in R$, then $S$ is flat.
3. If $R$ is integrally closed, but $S$ is not obtained by inverting one
   element of $r$, then I don't know an example where $(4)$ holds. For
   example, let $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $S = \mathbb{C}[x, \frac{y}{x}]$.
   This ring map comes from blowing up $\mathbb{C}^2$ at the origin.
   Note that $xS$ defines the exceptional divisor in the affine open set of
   the blow-up given by $\mathrm{Spec} S$.
   If $\mathfrak{q}$ is a maximal $S$-ideal containing $xS$,
   then $\mathfrak{q} \cap R = (x,y)R$ and
   $(\mathfrak{q} \cap R)S = xS$. Hence $S$ is not unramified over $R$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Interesting. Please, do you think it is possible to find a mild condition that will guarantee flatness of $R \subseteq S$ satisfying (1)-(4)?

Comment: I have expanded my earlier answer with some comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for expanding your answer!

Comment: Please, could you take a look at my recent question, which also deals with separability: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371948/separability-of-mathbbcx-over-its-mathbbc-subalgebras?noredirect=1&lq=1 Any ideas are welcome! Thank you.

Comment: In particular, I do not mind to restrict the above quoted question to the following: Assume that $R=\mathbb{C}+(h) \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x]$ is separable.(hence the four conditions of my current question are satisfied). Notice that $R$ is integrally closed iff $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$, so let's assume that $R$ is not integrally closed (this holds for any $h$ of degree $\geq 2$). Then is it possible to find an exact form of such $h$?